# Table resizing issue

Tags: tables

[image]

I am having the issue of width(size of the table). I want the 2nd table to be of the same width as the 1st one.
Kindly help me with this.
Thanks

Code of 2nd table is:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Priority} & \textbf{Details}                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
NR-01-001   & 1                 & Delivery: The system development process and deliverable documents shall conform to the process and deliverables dened in document \textbackslash{}CIIT-CE-02H DegreeProject Student's Handbook". \\ \hline
NR-01-002   & 1                 & Standard: The standard of the final product shall be of undergraduate level or above.                                                                                                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Use a `p` type column instead of `l` for the last column in both tabular environments. Make sure to use the identical width argument in both to get equally wide tables. (Something like `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{7cm}|}` used for both tables should result in both tables being equally wide.) Depending on the expected output, you could also give `tabularx` a try: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|}`(needs the `tabularx` package). Lastly, it could also be easier to just use a single `tabular` environment instead of two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use `tabularx` instead simple `tabular`. Its `X` (and from it derived ) column's types enables automatic determination of column width and, what is in your case important,  breaking text into multi lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|}
    \hline
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Priority} 
                    & \textbf{Details}  \\ 
    \hline
NR-01-001   & 1     & Delivery: The system development process and deliverable documents shall conform to the process and deliverables dened in document \textbackslash{}CIIT-CE-02H DegreeProject Student's Handbook". \\
    \hline
NR-01-002   & 1     & Standard: The standard of the final product shall be of undergraduate level or above.     \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: Thank you Zarko, it's absolutely what I want.

Comment: @ChQasim, you are welcome :-)